# Rot13 implementation: error in translate_string function

Tags: memory, c

I wrote a rot13.c program but I can tell something in my loop inside rot13_translate_string is causing the program to just print out blank lines.

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char rot13_translate_character(char c)
{
    if( 'A' <= c && c <= 'M' )
    {
            return c + 13;
    }
    else if( 'N' <= c && c <= 'Z' )
    {
            return c - 13;
    }
    else if( 'a' <= c && c <= 'm' )
    {
            return c + 13;
    }
    else if( 'n' <= c && c <= 'z' )
    {
            return c - 13;
    }
    else
    {
            return c;
    }
}

 char *rot13_translate_string(const char *str)
{
    int  len          = strlen(str);
    char *translation = calloc(len, sizeof(char));

    int i;

    do    //****HERE IN THIS SECTION
    {
            /* Translate each character, starting from the end of the string. */
            translation[len] = rot13_translate_character(str[len]);
            len--;
    } while( len < 0 ); //<

    return translation;
}
```

And here is the main (part of the same file) - is the condition for my for i = 1 ok?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if( argc < 2)
    {

            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s word [word ...]\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }

    /* Translate each of the arguments */
    int i;
    for( i = 1; i < argc; i++)     //*****IS this right?
    {
            char *translation =  rot13_translate_string( argv[i] );
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", translation);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `len--; } while( len < 0 );` should certainly be `while ( len >= 0 );`.

Comment: It would be useful to see the definition for `rot13_translate_string`. Note also that your code seems to assume that codes for characters representing letters are consecutive, but C doesn't guarantee that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As just it was pointed out by Janis is the control on the loop *do   ...  while*. It should be
`while( len >= 0 );`

A *"while" loop* runs while the control expression is *true* (and terminates once the expression becomes false). You define the variable *len* just before the loop and it cannot be `<0`.
So you never really enter in the loop.

You obtain a line for each input word because of `fprintf(stdout, "%s`**`\n`**`", translation);` line, where you print for each (empty) word a line (`\n`).

In other languages, for example in Pascal, there is "*repeat until*" loop construction, which continues to run *until* the control expression is true, and only after that it changes it terminates.
In that case you could use a condition with `<0`. 
In C to follow the same logic  you can use *while loop* and negate the condition. In your case
`} while (! (len < 0) );`